xfce4 panel is disappearing when applying panel profile from panel preferences in xubuntu 24.04
After a fresh install of Xubuntu 24.04 on a dell Inspiron 7559 laptop, I am exploring the Xfce desktop. I tried to change panel profile to one of the default profiles that came with Xubuntu, however the moment I apply any panel profile by right clicking the panel-> panel preferences-> profile, the panel at the top disappears.

I need to run xfce4-panel from terminal to get the panel back. I will not be able to save and restore any panel profile if this feature is broken. I would like to know what is causing this issue and how to fix it. I have found a crash log in /var/crash which are here.
